# Cannot access destination table on bulk insert c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to use SqlBulkCopy in order to insert plenty of rows in short time.
I get the error:"

> Cannot access destination table myTable.

Here is my code:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["myConnection"].ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(int)));
for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr["Col1"] = "Col1_" + i.toString();
   dr["Col2"] = i;
}
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkSql = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
   bulkSql.BatchSize = 10000;
   bulkSql.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
   bulkSql.ColumnMappings.Clear();
   bulkSql.ColumnMappings.Add("Col1", "Col1");
   bulkSql.ColumnMappings.Add("Col2", "Col2");
   bulkSql.DestinationTableName = "[myTable]"
   bulkSql.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working with your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlBulkCopy cannot access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894071/sqlbulkcopy-cannot-access-table)

Comment: I have full grants on that table and I already inserted data via linqtosql, but now I want to do it with bulk

Comment: I declared it in web.config, but sorry it's not that I don't want to show it, it's that I am not allowed to show it. Any fast way to check my connection string if it is ok?

Comment: You can't help me if you can't see my connection string? It's highly unprofessional to publish code that is used to a client and seriously unnecessary to see my connection string, because simply I can check if my connection string is valid and as I already did it is. Bulk is a step after inserting data, which is after executing queries in database, which is after connecting to a database. Clearly from the comments above you haven't payed that much attention on my description and title. Thank you for your time!

Comment: bulkSql.DestinationTableName = "myTable"; <<add a semi-colon and take out brackets. Also, add blkSql.Close(); after you write to server.

Comment: does the table definitely exist on `[dbo]` schema? Might be worth being explicit about your schema.

Comment: @kristech Unfortunately, I already tried without brackets but didn't work.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars The table exists in a schema that I created [mySchema], so I've tried:
bulkSql.DestinationTableName = "[mySchema].[UploadData]";
but still didn't work.

Comment: Can you try with less records say 500, if that works then increment it by another 500 rows and so on. Table lock may cause this issue.

Comment: And the connection string includes the db name? If the connection string connects to `master`, you will need to include that on the `DestinationTableName` as well.

Comment: Double check that the user in the connection has both `select` and `insert` permissions as well.

Comment: My apologies for not responding at all, but I couldnt have access to the pc till now.

Comment: @ParthaThakura I did tried that right now, but I got the same error.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars I have SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER grants. About your previous comment, I am not quite sure that I know how to check that. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: @L.Achilles does the connection string contain a reference to either `Database={YourDatabaseName}` or `Initial Catalog={YourDatabaseName}` if not then you will need to add the db to the destination as well, i.e. `YourDatabaseName.YourSchema.YourTable`.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars I use Initial Catalog={MyDatabaseName}

Answer (score 3):

I finally have found the answer. My table name is in [MyDatabase].[mySchema].[myTable]. So in web.config my connection string correctly had Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; but I also needed: 
    bulkSql.DestinationTableName = "[mySchema].[myTable]";
in order to run it succesfully. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. Would really appreciate if you vote for my comments above to that effect thanks :) .

Comment: @tigerswithguitars Oops sorry that I haven't done this already. I am quite new in stackoverflow community.
Actually I just checked it and I need 15 points of reputation and I have 13. Sorry!