# Inserting data to SQL server using Sqlbulkcopy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i'm having a error message sent everytime i try to copy data from a data table to an sql database using Sqlbulkcopy.
This is the code i'm using:

```
static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvFileData)
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-LNCGI78\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testdatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Table";
                foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error :System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access destination table.
i checked permissions to write in the table, all seems fine and i tried to insert some rows in it with success. I don't know what i'm missing or what i did wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlBulkCopy cannot access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894071/sqlbulkcopy-cannot-access-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word Table is a reserved word in SQL Server and as such you need to add brackets:

```
s.DestinationTableName = "dbo.[Table]";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem what  I did is just `s.DestinationTableName="[TableName]"`.
So no dbo.[TableName] just [TableName]